# Adding an element to a pre-initialized list in Java

Tags: java, list

If I want to define a list of strings containing three items `"Larry"`, `"Curly"` and `"Moe"`; and then later on I want to add `"Shemp"` to this list, is there any way to do this, which does not involve the use of 4 separate adds? What's the best way to complete this operation?

Edited for clarification: I'm using this list of 4 items as an example. In my actual program I need to create a much larger list (hence, why I am looking for a less cumbersome method). And the primary objective is that I would like to define some of the elements of the list right in when I am initializing it, but I also *need* to add a few elements to the list later on in the code.

Comment: Use `ArrayList` with `add` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to define a list of strings containing three items "Larry","Curly" and "Moe" [....] is there any way to do this, which does not involve the use of 4 separate adds ?

You can use the constructor  [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Larry","Curly","Moe"));
```

> and then later on I want to add "Shemp" to this list

Use the add method :

```
list.add("Shemp");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. But what is the issue with use of four `add`?

```
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList("Larry","Curly","Moe","Shemp"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to add items to my list **later on** in the code, not all 4 at once)

Answer (score 1):

Define a list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("Larry", "Curly", "Moe"));
```

then when you later want to add "Shemp" do:

```
list.add("Shemp");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Larry","Curly", "Shemp", "Moe"));
```